# how do you create when the speed hits zero the game shows a endscreen

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I tried things as a tic tac toe ending but it didn't work and I tried making a restart button that  also didn't show up

I  looked at mostly all reddit and stack  blogs that didn't answer my question

does anyone know how it can be done?

[This is the codepen in javascript](https://codepen.io/Matsklink/pen/VwdEVBj)

```js
// draw settings
const context = c.getContext `2d`; // canvas context
const drawDistance = 800; // how far ahead to draw
const cameraDepth = 2; // FOV of camera
const segmentLength = 100; // length of each road segment
const roadWidth = 500; // how wide is road
const curbWidth = 150; // with of warning track
const dashLineWidth = 9; // width of the dashed line
const maxPlayerX = 2e3; // limit player offset
const mountainCount = 30; // how many mountains are there
const timeDelta = 1 / 60; // inverse frame rate
const PI = Math.PI; // shorthand for Math.PI

// player settings
const height = 150; // high of player above ground
const maxSpeed = 500; // limit max player speed
const playerAccel = 1; // player forward acceleration
const playerBrake = -3; // player breaking acceleration
const turnControl = .3; // player turning rate
const jumpAccel = 25; // z speed added for jump
const springConstant = .01; // spring players pitch
const collisionSlow = .1; // slow down from collisions
const pitchLerp = .1; // rate camera pitch changes
const pitchSpringDamp = .9; // dampen the pitch spring
const elasticity = 1.2; // bounce elasticity
const centrifugal = .002; // how much turns pull player
const forwardDamp = .999; // dampen player z speed
const lateralDamp = .7; // dampen player x speed
const offRoadDamp = .98; // more damping when off road
const gravity = -1; // gravity to apply in y axis
const cameraTurnScale = 2; // how much to rotate camera
const worldRotateScale = .00005; // how much to rotate world

// level settings
const maxTime = 20; // time to start
const checkPointTime = 15; // add time at checkpoints
const checkPointDistance = 1e5; // how far between checkpoints
const maxDifficultySegment = 9e3; // how far until max difficulty
const roadEnd = 1e4; // how far until end of road

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// mouse input
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

mouseDown =
  mousePressed =
  mouseUpFrames =
  mouseX = 0;

onmouseup = e => mouseDown = 0;
onmousedown = e => mousePressed ? mouseDown = 1 : mousePressed = 1;
onmousemove = e => mouseX = e.x / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// math and helper functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Clamp = (v, a, b) => Math.min(Math.max(v, a), b);
ClampAngle = (a) => (a + PI) % (2 * PI) + (a + PI < 0 ? PI : -PI);
Lerp = (p, a, b) => a + Clamp(p, 0, 1) * (b - a);
R = (a = 1, b = 0) => Lerp((Math.sin(++randSeed) + 1) * 1e5 % 1, a, b);
LSHA = (l, s = 0, h = 0, a = 1) => `hsl(${h+hueShift},${s}%,${l}%,${a})`;

// simple 3d vector class
class Vec3 {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  Add = (v) => (
    v = v < 1e5 ? new Vec3(v, v, v) : v,
    new Vec3(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y, this.z + v.z));

  Multiply = (v) => (
    v = v < 1e5 ? new Vec3(v, v, v) : v,
    new Vec3(this.x * v.x, this.y * v.y, this.z * v.z));
}

// draw a trapazoid shaped poly
DrawPoly = (x1, y1, w1, x2, y2, w2, fillStyle) => {
  context.beginPath(context.fillStyle = fillStyle);
  context.lineTo(x1 - w1, y1 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x1 + w1, y1 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x2 + w2, y2 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x2 - w2, y2 | 0);
  context.fill();
}

// draw outlined hud text
DrawText = (text, posX) => {
  // scale text so it works in tiny CodePen iframe
  const size = c.height / 79;
  context.font = size + 'em impact'; // set font size
  context.fillStyle = LSHA(99, 0, 0, .5); // set font color
  context.fillText(text, posX, size * 14); // fill text
  context.lineWidth = size / 2.5; // line width
  context.strokeText(text, posX, size * 14); // outline text

  /*
  context.font = '9em impact';         // set font size
  context.fillStyle = LSHA(99,0,0,.5); // set font color
  context.fillText(text, posX, 129);   // fill text
  context.lineWidth = 3;               // line width
  context.strokeText(text, posX, 129); // outline text
  */
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// build the road with procedural generation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

roadGenLengthMax = // end of section
  roadGenLength = // distance left
  roadGenTaper = // length of taper
  roadGenFreqX = // X wave frequency 
  roadGenFreqY = // Y wave frequency
  roadGenScaleX = // X wave amplitude
  roadGenScaleY = 0; // Y wave amplitude
roadGenWidth = roadWidth; // starting road width
startRandSeed = randSeed = Date.now(); // set random seed
road = []; // clear road

// generate the road
for (i = 0; i < roadEnd * 2; ++i) // build road past end
{
  if (roadGenLength++ > roadGenLengthMax) // is end of section?
  {
    // calculate difficulty percent
    d = Math.min(1, i / maxDifficultySegment);

    // randomize road settings
    roadGenWidth = roadWidth * R(1 - d * .7, 3 - 2 * d); // road width
    roadGenFreqX = R(Lerp(d, .01, .02)); // X curves
    roadGenFreqY = R(Lerp(d, .01, .03)); // Y bumps
    roadGenScaleX = i > roadEnd ? 0 : R(Lerp(d, .2, .6)); // X scale
    roadGenScaleY = R(Lerp(d, 1e3, 2e3)); // Y scale

    // apply taper and move back
    roadGenTaper = R(99, 1e3) | 0; // random taper
    roadGenLengthMax = roadGenTaper + R(99, 1e3); // random length
    roadGenLength = 0; // reset length
    i -= roadGenTaper; // subtract taper
  }

  // make a wavy road
  x = Math.sin(i * roadGenFreqX) * roadGenScaleX;
  y = Math.sin(i * roadGenFreqY) * roadGenScaleY;
  road[i] = road[i] ? road[i] : {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    w: roadGenWidth
  };

  // apply taper from last section and lerp values
  p = Clamp(roadGenLength / roadGenTaper, 0, 1);
  road[i].x = Lerp(p, road[i].x, x);
  road[i].y = Lerp(p, road[i].y, y);
  road[i].w = i > roadEnd ? 0 : Lerp(p, road[i].w, roadGenWidth);

  // calculate road pitch angle
  road[i].a = road[i - 1] ?
    Math.atan2(road[i - 1].y - road[i].y, segmentLength) : 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// init game
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// reset everything
velocity = new Vec3(pitchSpring = pitchSpringSpeed = pitchRoad = hueShift = 0);

position = new Vec3(0, height); // set player start pos
nextCheckPoint = checkPointDistance; // init next checkpoint
time = maxTime; // set the start time
heading = randSeed; // random world heading

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update and render frame
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Update = () => {

  // get player road segment
  s = position.z / segmentLength | 0; // current road segment
  p = position.z / segmentLength % 1; // percent along segment

  // get lerped values between last and current road segment
  roadX = Lerp(p, road[s].x, road[s + 1].x);
  roadY = Lerp(p, road[s].y, road[s + 1].y) + height;
  roadA = Lerp(p, road[s].a, road[s + 1].a);

  // update player velocity
  lastVelocity = velocity.Add(0);
  velocity.y += gravity;
  velocity.x *= lateralDamp;
  velocity.z = Math.max(0, time ? forwardDamp * velocity.z : 0);

  // add velocity to position
  position = position.Add(velocity);

  // limit player x position (how far off road)
  position.x = Clamp(position.x, -maxPlayerX, maxPlayerX);

  // check if on ground
  if (position.y < roadY) {
    position.y = roadY; // match y to ground plane
    airFrame = 0; // reset air frames

    // get the dot product of the ground normal and the velocity
    dp = Math.cos(roadA) * velocity.y + Math.sin(roadA) * velocity.z;

    // bounce velocity against ground normal
    velocity = new Vec3(0, Math.cos(roadA), Math.sin(roadA))
      .Multiply(-elasticity * dp).Add(velocity);

    // apply player brake and accel
    velocity.z +=
      mouseDown ? playerBrake :
      Lerp(velocity.z / maxSpeed, mousePressed * playerAccel, 0);

    // check if off road
    if (Math.abs(position.x) > road[s].w) {
      velocity.z *= offRoadDamp; // slow down
      pitchSpring += Math.sin(position.z / 99) ** 4 / 99; // rumble
    }
  }

  // update player turning and apply centrifugal force
  turn = Lerp(velocity.z / maxSpeed, mouseX * turnControl, 0);
  velocity.x +=
    velocity.z * turn -
    velocity.z ** 2 * centrifugal * roadX;

  // update jump
  if (airFrame++ < 6 && time &&
    mouseDown && mouseUpFrames && mouseUpFrames < 9) {
    velocity.y += jumpAccel; // apply jump velocity
    airFrame = 9; // prevent jumping again
  }
  mouseUpFrames = mouseDown ? 0 : mouseUpFrames + 1;

  // pitch down with vertical velocity when in air
  airPercent = (position.y - roadY) / 99;
  pitchSpringSpeed += Lerp(airPercent, 0, velocity.y / 4e4);

  // update player pitch spring
  pitchSpringSpeed += (velocity.z - lastVelocity.z) / 2e3;
  pitchSpringSpeed -= pitchSpring * springConstant;
  pitchSpringSpeed *= pitchSpringDamp;
  pitchSpring += pitchSpringSpeed;
  pitchRoad = Lerp(pitchLerp, pitchRoad, Lerp(airPercent, -roadA, 0));
  playerPitch = pitchSpring + pitchRoad;

  // update heading
  heading = ClampAngle(heading + velocity.z * roadX * worldRotateScale);
  cameraHeading = turn * cameraTurnScale;

  // was checkpoint crossed?
  if (position.z > nextCheckPoint) {
    time += checkPointTime; // add more time
    nextCheckPoint += checkPointDistance; // set next checkpoint
    hueShift += 36; // shift hue
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw background - sky, sun/moon, mountains, and horizon
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // clear the screen and set size
  c.width = window.innerWidth, c.height = window.innerHeight;

  // pre calculate projection scale, flip y
  projectScale = (new Vec3(1, -1, 1)).Multiply(c.width / 2 / cameraDepth);

  // get horizon, offset, and light amount
  horizon = c.height / 2 - Math.tan(playerPitch) * projectScale.y;
  backgroundOffset = Math.sin(cameraHeading) / 2;
  light = Math.cos(heading);

  // create linear gradient for sky
  g = context.createLinearGradient(0, horizon - c.height / 2, 0, horizon);
  g.addColorStop(0, LSHA(39 + light * 25, 49 + light * 19, 230 - light * 19));
  g.addColorStop(1, LSHA(5, 79, 250 - light * 9));

  // draw sky as full screen poly
  DrawPoly(c.width / 2, 0, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2, g);

  // draw sun and moon (0=sun, 1=moon)
  for (i = 2; i--;) {
    // create radial gradient
    g = context.createRadialGradient(
      x = c.width * (.5 + Lerp(
        (heading / PI / 2 + .5 + i / 2) % 1,
        4, -4) - backgroundOffset),
      y = horizon - c.width / 5,
      c.width / 25,
      x, y, i ? c.width / 23 : c.width);
    g.addColorStop(0, LSHA(i ? 70 : 99));
    g.addColorStop(1, LSHA(0, 0, 0, 0));

    // draw full screen poly
    DrawPoly(c.width / 2, 0, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2, g);
  }

  // set random seed for mountains
  randSeed = startRandSeed;

  // draw mountains
  for (i = mountainCount; i--;) {
    angle = ClampAngle(heading + R(19));
    light = Math.cos(angle - heading);
    DrawPoly(
      x = c.width * (.5 + Lerp(angle / PI / 2 + .5, 4, -4) - backgroundOffset),
      y = horizon,
      w = R(.2, .8) ** 2 * c.width / 2,
      x + w * R(-.5, .5),
      y - R(.5, .8) * w, 0,
      LSHA(R(15, 25) + i / 3 - light * 9, i / 2 + R(19), R(220, 230)));
  }

  // draw horizon
  DrawPoly(
    c.width / 2, horizon, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2,
    LSHA(25, 30, 95));

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw road and objects
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // calculate road x offsets and projections
  for (x = w = i = 0; i < drawDistance + 1;) {
    p = new Vec3(x += w += road[s + i].x, // sum local road offsets
        road[s + i].y, (s + i) * segmentLength) // road y and z pos
      .Add(position.Multiply(-1)); // get local camera space

    // apply camera heading
    p.x = p.x * Math.cos(cameraHeading) - p.z * Math.sin(cameraHeading);

    // tilt camera pitch and invert z
    z = 1 / (p.z * Math.cos(playerPitch) - p.y * Math.sin(playerPitch));
    p.y = p.y * Math.cos(playerPitch) - p.z * Math.sin(playerPitch);
    p.z = z;

    // project road segment to canvas space
    road[s + i++].p = // projected road point
      p.Multiply(new Vec3(z, z, 1)) // projection
      .Multiply(projectScale) // scale
      .Add(new Vec3(c.width / 2, c.height / 2)); // center on canvas
  }

  // draw the road segments
  let segment2 = road[s + drawDistance]; // store the last segment
  for (i = drawDistance; i--;) // iterate in reverse
  {
    // get projected road points
    segment1 = road[s + i];
    p1 = segment1.p;
    p2 = segment2.p;

    // random seed and lighting
    randSeed = startRandSeed + s + i;
    light = Math.sin(segment1.a) * Math.cos(heading) * 99;

    // check near and far clip
    if (p1.z < 1e5 && p1.z > 0) {
      // fade in road resolution over distance
      if (i % (Lerp(i / drawDistance, 1, 9) | 0) == 0) {
        // ground
        DrawPoly(c.width / 2, p1.y, c.width / 2,
          c.width / 2, p2.y, c.width / 2,
          LSHA(25 + light, 30, 95));

        // curb if wide enough
        if (segment1.w > 400)
          DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * (segment1.w + curbWidth),
            p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * (segment2.w + curbWidth),
            LSHA(((s + i) % 19 < 9 ? 50 : 20) + light));

        // road and checkpoint marker
        DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * segment1.w,
          p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * segment2.w,
          LSHA(((s + i) * segmentLength % checkPointDistance < 300 ? 70 : 7) + light));

        // dashed lines if wide and close enough
        if ((segment1.w > 300) && (s + i) % 9 == 0 && i < drawDistance / 3)
          DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * dashLineWidth,
            p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * dashLineWidth,
            LSHA(70 + light));

        // save this segment
        segment2 = segment1;
      }

      // random object (tree or rock)
      if (R() < .2 && s + i > 29) {
        // player object collision check
        x = 2 * roadWidth * R(10, -10) * R(9); // choose object pos
        const objectHeight = (R(2) | 0) * 400; // choose tree or rock
        if (!segment1.h // dont hit same object
          &&
          Math.abs(position.x - x) < 200 // X
          &&
          Math.abs(position.z - (s + i) * segmentLength) < 200 // Z
          &&
          position.y - height < segment1.y + objectHeight + 200) // Y
        {
          // slow player and mark object as hit
          velocity = velocity.Multiply(segment1.h = collisionSlow);
        }

        // draw road object
        const alpha = Lerp(i / drawDistance, 4, 0); // fade in object
        if (objectHeight) {
          // tree trunk
          DrawPoly(x = p1.x + p1.z * x, p1.y, p1.z * 29,
            x, p1.y - 99 * p1.z, p1.z * 29,
            LSHA(5 + R(9), 50 + R(9), 29 + R(9), alpha));

          // tree leaves
          DrawPoly(x, p1.y - R(50, 99) * p1.z, p1.z * R(199, 250),
            x, p1.y - R(600, 800) * p1.z, 0,
            LSHA(25 + R(9), 80 + R(9), 9 + R(29), alpha));
        } else {
          // rock
          DrawPoly(x = p1.x + p1.z * x, p1.y, p1.z * R(200, 250),
            x + p1.z * (R(99, -99)), p1.y - R(200, 250) * p1.z, p1.z * R(99),
            LSHA(50 + R(19), 25 + R(19), 209 + R(9), alpha));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw and update time
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (mousePressed) {
    time = Clamp(time - timeDelta, 0, maxTime); // update time
    DrawText(Math.ceil(time), 9); // show time
    context.textAlign = 'right'; // right alignment
    DrawText(0 | position.z / 1e3, c.width - 9); // show distance
  } else {
    context.textAlign = 'center'; // center alignment
    DrawText('HUE JUMPER', c.width / 2); // draw title text
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(Update); // kick off next frame

}

Update(); // kick off update loop
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mplungjan it doesnt work it says unexpextect token and as result I get a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my comment because I tried to format as a comment.

```
if (mousePressed) {
  time = Clamp(time - timeDelta, 0, maxTime); // update time
  if (time <= 0) {
    DrawText("Done", 9); /* or clear the canvas and write text */
    return;
  }
  ...
```

```js
// draw settings
const context = c.getContext `2d`; // canvas context
const drawDistance = 800; // how far ahead to draw
const cameraDepth = 2; // FOV of camera
const segmentLength = 100; // length of each road segment
const roadWidth = 500; // how wide is road
const curbWidth = 150; // with of warning track
const dashLineWidth = 9; // width of the dashed line
const maxPlayerX = 2e3; // limit player offset
const mountainCount = 30; // how many mountains are there
const timeDelta = 1 / 60; // inverse frame rate
const PI = Math.PI; // shorthand for Math.PI

// player settings
const height = 150; // high of player above ground
const maxSpeed = 500; // limit max player speed
const playerAccel = 1; // player forward acceleration
const playerBrake = -3; // player breaking acceleration
const turnControl = .3; // player turning rate
const jumpAccel = 25; // z speed added for jump
const springConstant = .01; // spring players pitch
const collisionSlow = .1; // slow down from collisions
const pitchLerp = .1; // rate camera pitch changes
const pitchSpringDamp = .9; // dampen the pitch spring
const elasticity = 1.2; // bounce elasticity
const centrifugal = .002; // how much turns pull player
const forwardDamp = .999; // dampen player z speed
const lateralDamp = .7; // dampen player x speed
const offRoadDamp = .98; // more damping when off road
const gravity = -1; // gravity to apply in y axis
const cameraTurnScale = 2; // how much to rotate camera
const worldRotateScale = .00005; // how much to rotate world

// level settings
const maxTime = 20; // time to start
const checkPointTime = 15; // add time at checkpoints
const checkPointDistance = 1e5; // how far between checkpoints
const maxDifficultySegment = 9e3; // how far until max difficulty
const roadEnd = 1e4; // how far until end of road

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// mouse input
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

mouseDown =
  mousePressed =
  mouseUpFrames =
  mouseX = 0;

onmouseup = e => mouseDown = 0;
onmousedown = e => mousePressed ? mouseDown = 1 : mousePressed = 1;
onmousemove = e => mouseX = e.x / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// math and helper functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Clamp = (v, a, b) => Math.min(Math.max(v, a), b);
ClampAngle = (a) => (a + PI) % (2 * PI) + (a + PI < 0 ? PI : -PI);
Lerp = (p, a, b) => a + Clamp(p, 0, 1) * (b - a);
R = (a = 1, b = 0) => Lerp((Math.sin(++randSeed) + 1) * 1e5 % 1, a, b);
LSHA = (l, s = 0, h = 0, a = 1) => `hsl(${h+hueShift},${s}%,${l}%,${a})`;

// simple 3d vector class
class Vec3 {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  Add = (v) => (
    v = v < 1e5 ? new Vec3(v, v, v) : v,
    new Vec3(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y, this.z + v.z));

  Multiply = (v) => (
    v = v < 1e5 ? new Vec3(v, v, v) : v,
    new Vec3(this.x * v.x, this.y * v.y, this.z * v.z));
}

// draw a trapazoid shaped poly
DrawPoly = (x1, y1, w1, x2, y2, w2, fillStyle) => {
  context.beginPath(context.fillStyle = fillStyle);
  context.lineTo(x1 - w1, y1 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x1 + w1, y1 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x2 + w2, y2 | 0);
  context.lineTo(x2 - w2, y2 | 0);
  context.fill();
}

// draw outlined hud text
DrawText = (text, posX) => {
  // scale text so it works in tiny CodePen iframe
  const size = c.height / 79;
  context.font = size + 'em impact'; // set font size
  context.fillStyle = LSHA(99, 0, 0, .5); // set font color
  context.fillText(text, posX, size * 14); // fill text
  context.lineWidth = size / 2.5; // line width
  context.strokeText(text, posX, size * 14); // outline text

  /*
  context.font = '9em impact';         // set font size
  context.fillStyle = LSHA(99,0,0,.5); // set font color
  context.fillText(text, posX, 129);   // fill text
  context.lineWidth = 3;               // line width
  context.strokeText(text, posX, 129); // outline text
  */
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// build the road with procedural generation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

roadGenLengthMax = // end of section
  roadGenLength = // distance left
  roadGenTaper = // length of taper
  roadGenFreqX = // X wave frequency 
  roadGenFreqY = // Y wave frequency
  roadGenScaleX = // X wave amplitude
  roadGenScaleY = 0; // Y wave amplitude
roadGenWidth = roadWidth; // starting road width
startRandSeed = randSeed = Date.now(); // set random seed
road = []; // clear road

// generate the road
for (i = 0; i < roadEnd * 2; ++i) // build road past end
{
  if (roadGenLength++ > roadGenLengthMax) // is end of section?
  {
    // calculate difficulty percent
    d = Math.min(1, i / maxDifficultySegment);

    // randomize road settings
    roadGenWidth = roadWidth * R(1 - d * .7, 3 - 2 * d); // road width
    roadGenFreqX = R(Lerp(d, .01, .02)); // X curves
    roadGenFreqY = R(Lerp(d, .01, .03)); // Y bumps
    roadGenScaleX = i > roadEnd ? 0 : R(Lerp(d, .2, .6)); // X scale
    roadGenScaleY = R(Lerp(d, 1e3, 2e3)); // Y scale

    // apply taper and move back
    roadGenTaper = R(99, 1e3) | 0; // random taper
    roadGenLengthMax = roadGenTaper + R(99, 1e3); // random length
    roadGenLength = 0; // reset length
    i -= roadGenTaper; // subtract taper
  }

  // make a wavy road
  x = Math.sin(i * roadGenFreqX) * roadGenScaleX;
  y = Math.sin(i * roadGenFreqY) * roadGenScaleY;
  road[i] = road[i] ? road[i] : {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    w: roadGenWidth
  };

  // apply taper from last section and lerp values
  p = Clamp(roadGenLength / roadGenTaper, 0, 1);
  road[i].x = Lerp(p, road[i].x, x);
  road[i].y = Lerp(p, road[i].y, y);
  road[i].w = i > roadEnd ? 0 : Lerp(p, road[i].w, roadGenWidth);

  // calculate road pitch angle
  road[i].a = road[i - 1] ?
    Math.atan2(road[i - 1].y - road[i].y, segmentLength) : 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// init game
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// reset everything
velocity = new Vec3(pitchSpring = pitchSpringSpeed = pitchRoad = hueShift = 0);

position = new Vec3(0, height); // set player start pos
nextCheckPoint = checkPointDistance; // init next checkpoint
time = maxTime; // set the start time
heading = randSeed; // random world heading

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// update and render frame
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Update = () => {

  // get player road segment
  s = position.z / segmentLength | 0; // current road segment
  p = position.z / segmentLength % 1; // percent along segment

  // get lerped values between last and current road segment
  roadX = Lerp(p, road[s].x, road[s + 1].x);
  roadY = Lerp(p, road[s].y, road[s + 1].y) + height;
  roadA = Lerp(p, road[s].a, road[s + 1].a);

  // update player velocity
  lastVelocity = velocity.Add(0);
  velocity.y += gravity;
  velocity.x *= lateralDamp;
  velocity.z = Math.max(0, time ? forwardDamp * velocity.z : 0);

  // add velocity to position
  position = position.Add(velocity);

  // limit player x position (how far off road)
  position.x = Clamp(position.x, -maxPlayerX, maxPlayerX);

  // check if on ground
  if (position.y < roadY) {
    position.y = roadY; // match y to ground plane
    airFrame = 0; // reset air frames

    // get the dot product of the ground normal and the velocity
    dp = Math.cos(roadA) * velocity.y + Math.sin(roadA) * velocity.z;

    // bounce velocity against ground normal
    velocity = new Vec3(0, Math.cos(roadA), Math.sin(roadA))
      .Multiply(-elasticity * dp).Add(velocity);

    // apply player brake and accel
    velocity.z +=
      mouseDown ? playerBrake :
      Lerp(velocity.z / maxSpeed, mousePressed * playerAccel, 0);

    // check if off road
    if (Math.abs(position.x) > road[s].w) {
      velocity.z *= offRoadDamp; // slow down
      pitchSpring += Math.sin(position.z / 99) ** 4 / 99; // rumble
    }
  }

  // update player turning and apply centrifugal force
  turn = Lerp(velocity.z / maxSpeed, mouseX * turnControl, 0);
  velocity.x +=
    velocity.z * turn -
    velocity.z ** 2 * centrifugal * roadX;

  // update jump
  if (airFrame++ < 6 && time &&
    mouseDown && mouseUpFrames && mouseUpFrames < 9) {
    velocity.y += jumpAccel; // apply jump velocity
    airFrame = 9; // prevent jumping again
  }
  mouseUpFrames = mouseDown ? 0 : mouseUpFrames + 1;

  // pitch down with vertical velocity when in air
  airPercent = (position.y - roadY) / 99;
  pitchSpringSpeed += Lerp(airPercent, 0, velocity.y / 4e4);

  // update player pitch spring
  pitchSpringSpeed += (velocity.z - lastVelocity.z) / 2e3;
  pitchSpringSpeed -= pitchSpring * springConstant;
  pitchSpringSpeed *= pitchSpringDamp;
  pitchSpring += pitchSpringSpeed;
  pitchRoad = Lerp(pitchLerp, pitchRoad, Lerp(airPercent, -roadA, 0));
  playerPitch = pitchSpring + pitchRoad;

  // update heading
  heading = ClampAngle(heading + velocity.z * roadX * worldRotateScale);
  cameraHeading = turn * cameraTurnScale;

  // was checkpoint crossed?
  if (position.z > nextCheckPoint) {
    time += checkPointTime; // add more time
    nextCheckPoint += checkPointDistance; // set next checkpoint
    hueShift += 36; // shift hue
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw background - sky, sun/moon, mountains, and horizon
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // clear the screen and set size
  c.width = window.innerWidth, c.height = window.innerHeight;

  // pre calculate projection scale, flip y
  projectScale = (new Vec3(1, -1, 1)).Multiply(c.width / 2 / cameraDepth);

  // get horizon, offset, and light amount
  horizon = c.height / 2 - Math.tan(playerPitch) * projectScale.y;
  backgroundOffset = Math.sin(cameraHeading) / 2;
  light = Math.cos(heading);

  // create linear gradient for sky
  g = context.createLinearGradient(0, horizon - c.height / 2, 0, horizon);
  g.addColorStop(0, LSHA(39 + light * 25, 49 + light * 19, 230 - light * 19));
  g.addColorStop(1, LSHA(5, 79, 250 - light * 9));

  // draw sky as full screen poly
  DrawPoly(c.width / 2, 0, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2, g);

  // draw sun and moon (0=sun, 1=moon)
  for (i = 2; i--;) {
    // create radial gradient
    g = context.createRadialGradient(
      x = c.width * (.5 + Lerp(
        (heading / PI / 2 + .5 + i / 2) % 1,
        4, -4) - backgroundOffset),
      y = horizon - c.width / 5,
      c.width / 25,
      x, y, i ? c.width / 23 : c.width);
    g.addColorStop(0, LSHA(i ? 70 : 99));
    g.addColorStop(1, LSHA(0, 0, 0, 0));

    // draw full screen poly
    DrawPoly(c.width / 2, 0, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2, g);
  }

  // set random seed for mountains
  randSeed = startRandSeed;

  // draw mountains
  for (i = mountainCount; i--;) {
    angle = ClampAngle(heading + R(19));
    light = Math.cos(angle - heading);
    DrawPoly(
      x = c.width * (.5 + Lerp(angle / PI / 2 + .5, 4, -4) - backgroundOffset),
      y = horizon,
      w = R(.2, .8) ** 2 * c.width / 2,
      x + w * R(-.5, .5),
      y - R(.5, .8) * w, 0,
      LSHA(R(15, 25) + i / 3 - light * 9, i / 2 + R(19), R(220, 230)));
  }

  // draw horizon
  DrawPoly(
    c.width / 2, horizon, c.width / 2, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width / 2,
    LSHA(25, 30, 95));

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw road and objects
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // calculate road x offsets and projections
  for (x = w = i = 0; i < drawDistance + 1;) {
    p = new Vec3(x += w += road[s + i].x, // sum local road offsets
        road[s + i].y, (s + i) * segmentLength) // road y and z pos
      .Add(position.Multiply(-1)); // get local camera space

    // apply camera heading
    p.x = p.x * Math.cos(cameraHeading) - p.z * Math.sin(cameraHeading);

    // tilt camera pitch and invert z
    z = 1 / (p.z * Math.cos(playerPitch) - p.y * Math.sin(playerPitch));
    p.y = p.y * Math.cos(playerPitch) - p.z * Math.sin(playerPitch);
    p.z = z;

    // project road segment to canvas space
    road[s + i++].p = // projected road point
      p.Multiply(new Vec3(z, z, 1)) // projection
      .Multiply(projectScale) // scale
      .Add(new Vec3(c.width / 2, c.height / 2)); // center on canvas
  }

  // draw the road segments
  let segment2 = road[s + drawDistance]; // store the last segment
  for (i = drawDistance; i--;) // iterate in reverse
  {
    // get projected road points
    segment1 = road[s + i];
    p1 = segment1.p;
    p2 = segment2.p;

    // random seed and lighting
    randSeed = startRandSeed + s + i;
    light = Math.sin(segment1.a) * Math.cos(heading) * 99;

    // check near and far clip
    if (p1.z < 1e5 && p1.z > 0) {
      // fade in road resolution over distance
      if (i % (Lerp(i / drawDistance, 1, 9) | 0) == 0) {
        // ground
        DrawPoly(c.width / 2, p1.y, c.width / 2,
          c.width / 2, p2.y, c.width / 2,
          LSHA(25 + light, 30, 95));

        // curb if wide enough
        if (segment1.w > 400)
          DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * (segment1.w + curbWidth),
            p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * (segment2.w + curbWidth),
            LSHA(((s + i) % 19 < 9 ? 50 : 20) + light));

        // road and checkpoint marker
        DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * segment1.w,
          p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * segment2.w,
          LSHA(((s + i) * segmentLength % checkPointDistance < 300 ? 70 : 7) + light));

        // dashed lines if wide and close enough
        if ((segment1.w > 300) && (s + i) % 9 == 0 && i < drawDistance / 3)
          DrawPoly(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z * dashLineWidth,
            p2.x, p2.y, p2.z * dashLineWidth,
            LSHA(70 + light));

        // save this segment
        segment2 = segment1;
      }

      // random object (tree or rock)
      if (R() < .2 && s + i > 29) {
        // player object collision check
        x = 2 * roadWidth * R(10, -10) * R(9); // choose object pos
        const objectHeight = (R(2) | 0) * 400; // choose tree or rock
        if (!segment1.h // dont hit same object
          &&
          Math.abs(position.x - x) < 200 // X
          &&
          Math.abs(position.z - (s + i) * segmentLength) < 200 // Z
          &&
          position.y - height < segment1.y + objectHeight + 200) // Y
        {
          // slow player and mark object as hit
          velocity = velocity.Multiply(segment1.h = collisionSlow);
        }

        // draw road object
        const alpha = Lerp(i / drawDistance, 4, 0); // fade in object
        if (objectHeight) {
          // tree trunk
          DrawPoly(x = p1.x + p1.z * x, p1.y, p1.z * 29,
            x, p1.y - 99 * p1.z, p1.z * 29,
            LSHA(5 + R(9), 50 + R(9), 29 + R(9), alpha));

          // tree leaves
          DrawPoly(x, p1.y - R(50, 99) * p1.z, p1.z * R(199, 250),
            x, p1.y - R(600, 800) * p1.z, 0,
            LSHA(25 + R(9), 80 + R(9), 9 + R(29), alpha));
        } else {
          // rock
          DrawPoly(x = p1.x + p1.z * x, p1.y, p1.z * R(200, 250),
            x + p1.z * (R(99, -99)), p1.y - R(200, 250) * p1.z, p1.z * R(99),
            LSHA(50 + R(19), 25 + R(19), 209 + R(9), alpha));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // draw and update time
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (mousePressed) {
    time = Clamp(time - timeDelta, 0, maxTime); // update time
    if (time <= 0) {
      DrawText("Done", 9); /* or clear the canvas and write text */
      return;
    }
    DrawText(Math.ceil(time), 9); // show time
    context.textAlign = 'right'; // right alignment
    DrawText(0 | position.z / 1e3, c.width - 9); // show distance
  } else {
    context.textAlign = 'center'; // center alignment
    DrawText('HUE JUMPER', c.width / 2); // draw title text
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(Update); // kick off next frame

}

Update(); // kick off update loop
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: it still only gives me a white screen

Comment: As you can see it works in this snippet